# Comparison of two different versions of Taylor expansion

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am taking a numerical analysis course and, when explaining the approximation of the first order derivative, it uses the following Taylor expansion:

$$f(x+h) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(x)}{i!}h^i$$

Whereas, the formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series specifies that it is

$$f(x+h) =  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(-h)}{i!}(x-h)^i$$ since it would be centered around $-h$ isn't it?

Here, $h$ is the perturbation.

I feel I am making a really dumb mistake, but I can't find what that is.

Comment: The second form is not correct. You have probably copied it wrongly.

Comment: I can't find the problem though. What is it? I know one of them must be wrong...

Comment: If you put $x=h$ in the formula you get $f(2x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: What is the correct form to do it with the formula from Wikipedia then?

Comment: The first one is correct and it is the standard Taylor series expansion.

Comment: Yes, but I did not ask that. What is the mistake I made when using Wikipedia's formula? I also found that same formula in websites from various universities. I know the first one is correct. Why is the second one not?

Comment: Nowhere on Wikipedia can I find this weird and wrong formula. We can only help if you show us how you derived it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition
1.- I know the second formula in my post is incorrect
2.- Using the one on wikipedia (From the links I just gave you), I TRIED to write them in terms of $x$ and $h$. I KNOW it is wrong. I know the first one is right. I want to know how to reinterpret said formula (from Wikipedia) in terms of $x$ and $h$ so that it looks like the first, correct formula in this post

Comment: @TheBosco Wikipedia formula equals to $f(x),$ not $f(x+h).$ Second thing that seems to be a wrong interpretation of that formula is $(-h)$ in the numerator. I would write $h.$